# What are the human bone rotation limits for fingers?

Tags: animation, blend-files, pose-mode, object-mode

Pose tool to aid in teaching animation using a non-traditional technique. Also to be used to speed up animations and walk cycles. I'm not blessed with wealth to give but I offer the gift of knowledge. Please learn, teach, and enjoy.

[image]

Does anybody know the human bone rotation limits for fingers?

Comment: I can't tell if you're looking to share your .blend or ask a question; this site is dedicated pretty narrowly on answering questions, so if it's the former I suggest posting it on [blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/)/[blendswap](https://www.blendswap.com/) and/or submitting it to [blendernation](https://www.blendernation.com/) instead.

Comment: Both. New at this and not on a pc.